# How to print specific content over a loop in Ansible

Tags: networking, automation, ansible

I'm a bit stuck with Ansible trying to print some variables from a return of F5.

I'm trying to print which nodes are configured in a determinated pool. I can get all the result:

```
TASK [f5_getpoolmembers : Ver IPs de un pool] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'pool_createdby_ansible_f5']) => 
  msg:
  - pool_createdby_ansible_f5
  - - address: 10.10.10.34
      connection_limit: 0
      description: prova_ansible_pool
      dynamic_ratio: 1
      ephemeral: 'no'
      fqdn_autopopulate: 'yes'
      full_path: /Common/10.10.10.34:80
      inherit_profile: 'yes'
      logging: 'no'
      monitors: []
      name: 10.10.10.34:80
      partition: Common
      priority_group: 0
      rate_limit: 'no'
      ratio: 1
      real_session: user-enabled
      real_state: unchecked
      state: present
    - address: 10.100.250.5
      connection_limit: 0
      dynamic_ratio: 1
      ephemeral: 'no'
      fqdn_autopopulate: 'no'
      full_path: /Common/10.100.250.5:80
      inherit_profile: 'yes'
      logging: 'no'
      monitors: []
      name: 10.100.250.5:80
      partition: Common
      priority_group: 0
      rate_limit: 'no'
      ratio: 1
      real_session: user-enabled
      real_state: unchecked
      state: present
```

with that code:

```yaml
- name: "Ver IPs de un pool"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{item.name}}"
      - "{{item.members}}"
  loop: "{{pool_facts.ltm_pools}}"
  loop_control:
    label:
      - "{{item.name}}"
  when: item.name is search "ansible"
```

The problem is when I try to print only the `name` for every node in the pool. I can't find the way to do it. Tried many options like nested or subelements, but didn't work. If i try to print only the `name`, I just get the first node:

```
TASK [f5_getpoolmembers : Ver IPs de un pool] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'pool_createdby_ansible_f5']) => 
  msg:
  - pool_createdby_ansible_f5
  - 10.10.10.34:80
```

Doing this:

```yaml
- name: "Ver IPs de un pool"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{item.name}}"
      - "{{item.members[0].name}}"
```

I know that it's wrong, so that's why I'm here to get some advices.

Edit: Added the complete structure of the pool:

```
    ltm_pools:
    - active_member_count: 0
      all_avg_queue_entry_age: 0
      all_max_queue_entry_age_ever: 0
      all_max_queue_entry_age_recently: 0
      all_num_connections_queued_now: 0
      all_num_connections_serviced: 0
      all_queue_head_entry_age: 0
      allow_nat: 'yes'
      allow_snat: 'yes'
      availability_status: unknown
      available_member_count: 3
      client_ip_tos: pass-through
      client_link_qos: pass-through
      current_sessions: 0
      enabled_status: enabled
      full_path: /Common/pool_createdby_ansible_f5
      ignore_persisted_weight: 'no'
      lb_method: ratio-member
      member_count: 3
      members:
      - address: 10.10.10.34
        connection_limit: 0
        description: prova_ansible_pool
        dynamic_ratio: 1
        ephemeral: 'no'
        fqdn_autopopulate: 'yes'
        full_path: /Common/10.10.10.34:80
        inherit_profile: 'yes'
        logging: 'no'
        monitors: []
        name: 10.10.10.34:80
        partition: Common
        priority_group: 0
        rate_limit: 'no'
        ratio: 1
        real_session: user-enabled
        real_state: unchecked
        state: present
      - address: 10.100.250.5
        connection_limit: 0
        dynamic_ratio: 1
        ephemeral: 'no'
        fqdn_autopopulate: 'no'
        full_path: /Common/10.100.250.5:80
        inherit_profile: 'yes'
        logging: 'no'
        monitors: []
        name: 10.100.250.5:80
        partition: Common
        priority_group: 0
        rate_limit: 'no'
        ratio: 1
        real_session: user-enabled
        real_state: unchecked
        state: present
      - address: 10.55.55.4
        connection_limit: 0
        dynamic_ratio: 1
        ephemeral: 'no'
        fqdn_autopopulate: 'no'
        full_path: /Common/10.55.55.4:80
        inherit_profile: 'yes'
        logging: 'no'
        monitors: []
        name: 10.55.55.4:80
        partition: Common
        priority_group: 0
        rate_limit: 'no'
        ratio: 1
        real_session: user-enabled
        real_state: unchecked
        state: present
      minimum_active_members: 0
      minimum_up_members: 0
      minimum_up_members_action: failover
      minimum_up_members_checking: 'no'
      name: pool_createdby_ansible_f5
      pool_avg_queue_entry_age: 0
      pool_max_queue_entry_age_ever: 0
      pool_max_queue_entry_age_recently: 0
      pool_num_connections_queued_now: 0
      pool_num_connections_serviced: 0
      pool_queue_head_entry_age: 0
      priority_group_activation: 0
      queue_depth_limit: 0
      queue_on_connection_limit: 'no'
      queue_time_limit: 0
      reselect_tries: 0
      server_ip_tos: pass-through
      server_link_qos: pass-through
      server_side_bits_in: 0
      server_side_bits_out: 0
      server_side_current_connections: 0
      server_side_max_connections: 0
      server_side_pkts_in: 0
      server_side_pkts_out: 0
      server_side_total_connections: 0
      service_down_action: none
      slow_ramp_time: 10
      status_reason: The children pool member(s) either don't have service checking enabled, or service check results are not available yet
      total_requests: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements), indeed.
When you are using the `subelements('dictionary_key')` filter, then you end up with:

- `item.0`: an item from the list of your loop
- `item.1`: an item from the nested list inside `dictionary_key` of each `item.0` item

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no  
        
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: 
          - "{{ item.0.name }}"
          - "{{ item.1.name }}"
      loop_control:
        label:
          - "{{ item.0.name }}"
      loop: "{{ pools_facts.ltm_pools | subelements('members') }}"
      when: "'ansible' in item.0.name"
      vars:
        pools_facts: 
          ltm_pools:
            - active_member_count: 0
              all_avg_queue_entry_age: 0
              all_max_queue_entry_age_ever: 0
              all_max_queue_entry_age_recently: 0
              all_num_connections_queued_now: 0
              all_num_connections_serviced: 0
              all_queue_head_entry_age: 0
              allow_nat: 'yes'
              allow_snat: 'yes'
              availability_status: unknown
              available_member_count: 3
              client_ip_tos: pass-through
              client_link_qos: pass-through
              current_sessions: 0
              enabled_status: enabled
              full_path: /Common/pool_createdby_ansible_f5
              ignore_persisted_weight: 'no'
              lb_method: ratio-member
              member_count: 3
              members:
                - address: 10.10.10.34
                  connection_limit: 0
                  description: prova_ansible_pool
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
                  ephemeral: 'no'
                  fqdn_autopopulate: 'yes'
                  full_path: /Common/10.10.10.34:80
                  inherit_profile: 'yes'
                  logging: 'no'
                  monitors: []
                  name: 10.10.10.34:80
                  partition: Common
                  priority_group: 0
                  rate_limit: 'no'
                  ratio: 1
                  real_session: user-enabled
                  real_state: unchecked
                  state: present
                - address: 10.100.250.5
                  connection_limit: 0
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
                  ephemeral: 'no'
                  fqdn_autopopulate: 'no'
                  full_path: /Common/10.100.250.5:80
                  inherit_profile: 'yes'
                  logging: 'no'
                  monitors: []
                  name: 10.100.250.5:80
                  partition: Common
                  priority_group: 0
                  rate_limit: 'no'
                  ratio: 1
                  real_session: user-enabled
                  real_state: unchecked
                  state: present
                - address: 10.55.55.4
                  connection_limit: 0
                  dynamic_ratio: 1
                  ephemeral: 'no'
                  fqdn_autopopulate: 'no'
                  full_path: /Common/10.55.55.4:80
                  inherit_profile: 'yes'
                  logging: 'no'
                  monitors: []
                  name: 10.55.55.4:80
                  partition: Common
                  priority_group: 0
                  rate_limit: 'no'
                  ratio: 1
                  real_session: user-enabled
                  real_state: unchecked
                  state: present
              minimum_active_members: 0
              minimum_up_members: 0
              minimum_up_members_action: failover
              minimum_up_members_checking: 'no'
              name: pool_createdby_ansible_f5
              pool_avg_queue_entry_age: 0
              pool_max_queue_entry_age_ever: 0
              pool_max_queue_entry_age_recently: 0
              pool_num_connections_queued_now: 0
              pool_num_connections_serviced: 0
              pool_queue_head_entry_age: 0
              priority_group_activation: 0
              queue_depth_limit: 0
              queue_on_connection_limit: 'no'
              queue_time_limit: 0
              reselect_tries: 0
              server_ip_tos: pass-through
              server_link_qos: pass-through
              server_side_bits_in: 0
              server_side_bits_out: 0
              server_side_current_connections: 0
              server_side_max_connections: 0
              server_side_pkts_in: 0
              server_side_pkts_out: 0
              server_side_total_connections: 0
              service_down_action: none
              slow_ramp_time: 10
              status_reason: The children pool member(s) either don't have service checking enabled, or service check results are not available yet
              total_requests: 0
```

This gives the output:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['pool_createdby_ansible_f5']) => {
    "msg": [
        "pool_createdby_ansible_f5",
        "10.10.10.34:80"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['pool_createdby_ansible_f5']) => {
    "msg": [
        "pool_createdby_ansible_f5",
        "10.100.250.5:80"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['pool_createdby_ansible_f5']) => {
    "msg": [
        "pool_createdby_ansible_f5",
        "10.55.55.4:80"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. Ansible shows me an error: *****************************************************************************************************
       fatal:[localhost]:FAILED!=>msg: obj must be a list of dicts or a nested dict

Comment: Means you are not showing us the important part then.
Please show the structure of the whole `pool_facts.ltm_pools` var and not just part of it.

Comment: Thanks. Just added the whole output from the variable pool_facts on first message.

Comment: Retested with the exact structure that you have provided and it gives the expect result, are you sure you are using the exact loop and message from the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have built a successful playbook. I chose to list more options than names of the members though. You could modify this to spit out just their names. As a note my playbokk has the variable poolName for a survey. Here is my playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: collect device info
    bigip_device_info:
      gather_subset:
        - ltm-pools
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: f5pools

  - name: Display Config for a specific pool using a variable
    debug:
     var: item
    loop: "{{ f5pools | json_query(pool_name) }}"
    vars:
     pool_name: "ltm_pools[?name=='{{ poolName }}'].{name: name, Method: lb_method, Members: members[*].{name: name, state:real_state }, Monitors: monitors}"
```

You could modify it for just the names using:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: collect device info
    bigip_device_info:
      gather_subset:
        - ltm-pools
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: f5pools

  - name: Display Config for a specific pool using a variable
    debug:
     var: item
    loop: "{{ f5pools | json_query(pool_name) }}"
    vars:
     pool_name: "ltm_pools[?name=='{{ poolName }}'].members[*].name"
```

Which worked see output:

```
{
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "item": [
        "1.1.1.2:443",
        "1.1.1.3:443"
    ],
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_item_label": [
        "1.1.1.2:443",
        "1.1.1.3:443"
    ]
}
```